# Copy/Paste to SP 2010 Page does not keep formatting?

Tags: wiki, formatting, pages, wiki-pages, copy-and-paste

I am trying to copy a formatted Word 2010 document and paste it into a SharePoint 2010 page. Most of the formatting comes over to SharePoint fine, EXCEPT for the indentation of the lines.

Is there anything I can do for the line indent formatting to paste over as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generally boils down to differences between Word's way of representing a document and HTML/CSS's approximations of such. One of the big areas they differ is indentation - SharePoint does its best to migrate the formatting but it doesn't always work.

There are a couple things you can do about this:

1. Use another tool to convert the document into HTML/CSS and paste the result into SharePoint. There's a lot of options out there for this, though I have to say I don't put much faith in conversion tools. One potential option: [Word to Clean HTML](http://word2cleanhtml.com/)
2. After pasting in the document, find the trouble spots and manually fix them. This is the 'brute force' approach and not much of an answer =)
3. Modify the CSS styles that SharePoint generates to try and fix the indentation. Very painful... I have done this before and will not be doing it again.
4. Write the HTML from scratch. This is what I prefer to do whenever possible - you avoid bringing over the massive 'cruft' that a Word document generates when converted to HTML and have a lot of control over the styling. The downside is that if you have a really long document, this is going to take a while.

I would recommend trying #1 and falling back to #4 if you can't find a good tool.

Comment: Thanks! I gave the tool you mentioned in step 1 a try and it retains the indents!!! It doesn't seem to care much for other formatting but indents are what matters for a user. So thank YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have any idea if this can be achieved?